# Строка выполняется после цикла, хотя стоит раньше

Tags: python, циклы, tkinter

Есть функция, выполняющая определенный цикл. Ее побочным эффектом должно быть изменение цвета кнопки. При вызове функции кнопка меняет цвет ПОСЛЕ завершения цикла, хотя стоит выше. Вопрос: как это работает?
Например:

```
def destiny(event):
    global go                           #добавил на случай проблемы с простр-м имен
    clock = 68468
    go.configure(background='#aaaaaa')  #меняем цвет тут
    start = int(time.time())
    end = int(start + (clock * 60))
    while True:
        stop = int(time.time())
        if stop == end:
            print('Hello, world')
            break
```

Похоже, ошибки тут нет, но есть неочевидная логика.
З.Ы.: с вашего позволения, импорты, объявление окна, кнопки и пр. я опущу

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если эта функция выполняется по событию `GUI`, то другие события `GUI` не будут обработаны, пока ваша функция не окончится. Вы тормозите цикл обработки событий `GUI` вашей долгой обработкой события, поэтому ничего и не обновляется. `GUI` обычно однопоточен и выполняется в основном потоке приложения (хотя если это `tkinter`, то наверное он выполняется в своём отдельном потоке, но не суть).

Если вы хотите, чтобы какой-то долгий процесс выполнялся в обработчике события `GUI`, вы должны запустить его отдельным потоком и как можно быстрее завершить обработку события. Причём, если речь о `tkinter`, то у него там есть свои какие-то потоки специальные, нужно, наверное, использовать их, а не обычные потоки  питона.

Хотя по-хорошему нужно всё-таки больше информации о вашем коде. Но в общих чертах работа всех `GUI` и обработка ими событий примерно одинаковы - это один поток, который обрабатывает очередь событий. И пока текущее событие не завершилось, другие события (включая отрисовку тех обновлений интерфейса, которые вы сделали) не будут выполнены.